# Combining web2py authentication decorators

Tags: python, web2py

In web2py I am trying to combine two authentication decorators to a method.

```
@auth.requires_permission('read', 'inv_header')
@auth.requires_permission('read', 'inv_detail')
```

My understanding is that I do it like this:

```
@auth.requires(auth.requires_permission('read', 'inv_header') and \
auth.requires_permission('read', 'inv_detail'))
```

but I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/restricted.py", line 224, in restricted
    exec ccode in environment
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/applications/niptview/controllers/batch.py", line 317, in <module>
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/globals.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
  File "/opt/web-apps/web2py/gluon/tools.py", line 3437, in f
    flag = condition()
TypeError: decorator() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

web2py™ Version 2.9.12-stable+timestamp.2015.01.17.06.11.03
Python  Python 2.7.5: /usr/bin/python (prefix: /usr)

Is there something that I am missing?

My environment is as follows:

```
web2py™ Version 2.9.12-stable+timestamp.2015.01.17.06.11.03
Python  Python 2.7.5: /usr/bin/python (prefix: /usr)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `@auth.requires`, you must use `auth.has_permission`, not `auth.requires_permission` (the latter is a decorator).

Comment: Thanks Anthony. That would make a good example in the web2py book under the section Compbining Requirements  (http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Combining-requirements).